# Downcasting from Serializable to LinkedList<Class>

Tags: java, android, linked-list, classcastexception, serializable

I'm trying to send a LinkedList from an Activity to an other one.
In the first Activity I have:

```
LinkedList<Class> codaActivity;
/* Lots of code here... */
Intent intent = new Intent(this, codaActivity.remove());
intent.putExtra("codaRedditi", codaActivity); // this is putExtra(String, Serializable)
startActivity(intent);
```

In the second one, instead:

```
// The following throws a ClassCastException
codaRedditi=(LinkedList<Class>) (getIntent().getSerializableExtra("codaRedditi"));
```

When I try to run my app, the DVM throws a ClassCastException caused by that code (and talking about an ArrayList, that absolutely does't exists in the code! O.O)

What can be the mistake?

Comment: So you say, that the type of `codeActivity` is `LinkedList<Class>`? Please add the declaration of `codeActivity` to your question.

Comment: Sorry yes, it is...now I'm going to edit my question ;)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the intent you are accessing is the one you have created? Try to debug the intent, for instance with outputting:

`getIntent().getSerializableExtra("codaRedditi").getClass()`

or the object itself:

`getIntent().getSerializableExtra("codaRedditi")`

What do you receive?

Also are you sure you are using the right `LinkedList` where you do the cast? Look into the imports, does it state: `java.util.LinkedList`

Comment: Thanks, I´ll try this evening and I´ll let you know ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `intent` is instance of `LinkedList`?

Trying:

```
codaRedditi=new LinkedList((List)(getIntent().getSerializableExtra("codaRedditi")));
```

Comment: No, Intent isn't a LinkedList, but Intent.getSerializedExtra() returns a Serializable, that LinkedList is.
I've tried your code, but Eclipse reminds me that LinkedList hasn't a constructor with a List parameter...

Comment: @user1726800 But it [does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#LinkedList(java.util.Collection)! Are you sure you are using `java.util.LinkedList` for the cast, respectively in the declaration?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList.html#LinkedList%28%29
Yes I am. Here I can see only an emty constructor and another one, that requires a Collection, that isn´t a List..!

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
public Intent putExtra (String name, Serializable value)

Since: API Level 1
Add extended data to the intent. The name must include a package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

Parameters
name    The name of the extra data, with package prefix.
value   The Serializable data value.
```

It says, the "name" field" should have package prefix like 'com.blah.something". Maybe this is causing the problem.

Comment: I tried editing the two strings, but nothing different happens :S